# Не могу поставить русский язык вывода OWM

Tags: python, бот, openweathermap, weather

Задал через конфиг здесь вывод на русском языке информации про погоду с помощью Open Weather Map. Бьюсь уже пол часа, он отказывается принимать русский язык. Через конфиг внутри такая же проблема. Ведь не может быть вывод на английском просто потому что у меня на компьютере стоит английский язык? В чем проблема?

```
import amino
import gtts
import requests
import os
import random
from pyowm import OWM
from termcolor import colored
from gtts import gTTS
from pyowm.utils.config import get_default_config
from pyowm.utils import timestamps, formatting


from threading import Thread
def main(data):
    Thread(target=on_message, args=(data, )).start()


def on_message(data: amino.objects.Event):
    global ban
    global tim
    global nom
    chatId: str = data.message.chatId
    nickname: str = data.message.author.nickname
    content: str = data.message.content
    messageId: str = data.message.messageId
    message_time: int = int(data.message.createdTime[17:19])
    userId: str= data.message.author.userId
    if content.lower().startswith("!погода"):
        config_dict = get_default_config()
        config_dict['language'] = 'ru'  
        owm = OWM('da1b5955f35250db10beb26ee0fd88a9', config_dict)
        mgr = owm.weather_manager()
        place = data.message.content.split("@")[1].replace("@", "")[0: 50]
        monitoring = owm.weather_manager().weather_at_place(place)
        weather = monitoring.weather
        status = weather.temperature('celsius') 
        sub_client.send_message(message=(f' {status} in {place}'), chatId=data.message.chatId)
```

Comment: https://qna.habr.com/q/793785

Comment: Не работает. Увы.
{'temp': 27.12, 'temp_max': 27.29, 'temp_min': 25.52, 'feels_like': 28.31, 'temp_kf': None} in Киев

Comment: Ну так выводите не весь статус, а только `status['temp']` например, и in замените на "в"

Comment: а что именно нужно локализовать на другой язык?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Не работает. Увы. {'temp': 27.12, 'temp_max': 27.29, 'temp_min': 25.52, 'feels_like': 28.31, 'temp_kf': None} in Киев

Все работает. Название города у вас приходит локализованным, а "in" вы в коде сами добавляете в последней строке:

```
sub_client.send_message(message=(f' {status} in {place}'), chatId=data.message.chatId)
```

Чтобы вместо полного словаря `status` выводилась температура, нужно получить из `status` значение по какому-то из ключей, пример:

```
sub_client.send_message(message=(f' {status["temp"]} градусов (ощущается как {status["feels_like"]}) в {place}'), chatId=data.message.chatId)
```